# No autocompletion on Eclipse(Helios)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, autocomplete, helios

I'm having a problem with the autocomplete option in Eclipse (Helios).
I've already checked Windows->Preferences->PHP->Editor->Content Assist and everything seems to be correct there.
And when I do get completions when I write "self::" in any of my classes, but this is the only situation I get it.

For example..
"parent::"
or
"$this->"..
Don't work at all.. any ideas?

Btw, I'm working under Lunix, Ubuntu 10.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like updating Eclipse to Build id: 20100917-0705 solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

1) .project file contains:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature>
```

2) .buildpath contains:

```
<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
```

3) Right-click project and go to `Configure -> Add PHP Support`

4) Are you using a namespace in your code? If so, does completion work without a namespace i.e. in a global namespace

I can also see quite a few open issues in [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi) related to code completion in PDT. Take a look.

Comment: Both entries on those files are present.
The Configure->Add PHP Support does not appear to be selectable on my project.. maybe it's already added?

Comment: The only situations I can get completion are on "self::" as I've already mentioned above and when I do Ctrl+Space on an empty space, in which case it lists the predefined variables of PHP, such as $_SERVER, $_PUT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that yoy've already tried the basic solutions that are documented across the web (phpnature, add php support, buildpath, etc.) it's probably best to look at the logs and provide any error that occurs when you try to call auto-completion.

You can "tail" the log and check if anything appears when asking for an autocomplete (press Ctrl+Space after writing "$this->" inside a method of a class):

`tail myWorkspace/.metadata/.log -f`

The error that appears may be usefull for searching google or for including here for others to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just upgrade eclipse you should rename/remove workspace/.metadata

some times there is compatibility issues...